# get char from txt file and write on standard output, C++

Tags: c++, file, get, ifstream, cout

I want to get char by char from txt file and write on standard output, in C++.

```
     std::ifstream fajl;
     fajl.open("radar.txt", ios::in);
     fajl.get(zn);
     std::cout<<zn;
```

This should write first char on screen but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Try `std::cout<<zn << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you just forget namespace for `ios::in`?
This works for me:

```
char zn;
std::ifstream fajl;
fajl.open("test.txt", std::ios::in);
fajl.get(zn);
std::cout << zn;
```

Comment: sorry, I answered up there

Comment: Your answer didn't work for me still, it doesn't work